# Best way to repoint a patio with strong mortar?

Tags: patio, mortar, repoint

In our previous home, we had a patio laid in two sections. The first time, the workmen carefully filled the gaps with pre-mixed mortar. The second time, a different workman brushed dry mortar into the cracks and watered it. Although the second section was done years before the first, it was also the first to crack and disintegrate. The original section was still intact when we moved out.

This chimes with what I've heard elsewhere which is that pre-mixed mortar is much stronger and longer lasting than the dry brushing method. Presuming it's true, it's also not surprising, since the water is added in the correct ratio & mixed through thoroughly.

In our new house, most of the patio mortar has long gone so I set about repointing it with pre-mixed mortar. I've not done this before and it proved a disaster. It takes ages to work it in and smooth it with a trowel, and even then there's a mess of mortar everywhere around the join. Originally I was able to wash this off with a scrubbing brush but the last batch dried hard faster & I can't shift it at all.

So: how can I learn the technique of working in wet mortar, faster, without making a mess? Or is the secret to clean it up faster before it dries, and if so how do you do it without "cleaning" the mortar between the slabs where you want it by accident? Or is it better just to give up, use the dry brush method and hope for the best, being prepared to re-do it after a few years?